# Find first and last string words according to ascending alphabetical order

Tags: c, arrays

As topic, the number of words to key in is determined by the user. Assume it is <=10. I have made some comments on the code to errors im facing, which lead to the comparison of string part not working obviously.

```
int main()
{
    int size, i;
    char wordArray[10][20]; // buffer of 10 words of 20 length
    char first[20]; // buffer 20 length
    char last[20]; // buffer 20 length
    printf("Enter size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter %d words separated by space: ", size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", wordArray[i]);
    }
    findWord(wordArray, size, &first, &last);
}

void findWord(char word[][20], int size, char *first, char *last)
{
    *first = word[i]; // initialize to first element. 
    *last = word[i];
    printf("first = %s", first); // for debugging purposes I got some weird symbol as prefix before my first element of word. Why is it so?
    printf("last = %s", last);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(word[i], *first) > 1)
        {
            *last = *first;
            *first = word[i];
        }
        else if (strcmp(word[i], *last) < 1)
        {
            *last = word[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The  strcmp()  function compares the two strings s1 and s2.  It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if  s1  is  found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2. Your comparison should be strcmp(...) < 0 and strcmp(...) > 0

Comment: `int i=0;` should be placed at the start of `findWord` function.

Comment: @HenkKok, Thanks for pointing that out. But it's the the major issue here as described in my post.

Comment: `*first = word[i];` is strange : `*first` is a char while `word[i]` is a pointer to char. Use [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) modify the prototype of the function to `void findWord(char word[][20], int size, char **first, char **last)` to pass `first` by reference (`&first`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions which do not perform exactly the same thing :

- Passing a pointer to char by argument. After calling the function, `first` points to first in alphabetical order `words[i][0]`. After calling the function, if `words[i]` is modified, `first` (seen as a string) will change too. To compile : `gcc main.c -o main`

  ```
  #include<string.h>
  #include<stdio.h>

  void findWord(char word[][20], int size, char **first, char **last);

  int main()
  {
      int size, i;
      char wordArray[10][20]; // buffer of 10 words of 20 length
      //   char first[20]; // buffer 20 length
      //   char last[20]; // buffer 20 length

      char* first;
      char* last;
      printf("Enter size: ");
      scanf("%d", &size);
      printf("Enter %d words separated by space: ", size);
      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
          scanf("%s", wordArray[i]);
      }
      findWord(wordArray, size, &first, &last);

      printf("first = %s\n", first); 
      printf("last = %s\n", last);
  }

  void findWord(char word[][20], int size, char **first, char **last)
  {
      int i = 0;
      *first = word[i]; // initialize to first element. 
      *last = word[i];


      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
          if (strcmp(word[i], *first) < 0)
          {
              // *last = *first;
              *first = word[i];
          }
          else if (strcmp(word[i], *last) > 0)
          {
              *last = word[i];
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Second solution : declaring `first` as an array of char (`char first[20]` and using [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) to copy the string `words[i]`. After calling the function, if `words[i]` is modified, `first` (seen as a string) will be left unchanged.

  ```
  #include<string.h>
  #include<stdio.h>

  void findWord(char word[][20], int size, char *first, char *last);

  int main()
  {
      int size, i;
      char wordArray[10][20]; // buffer of 10 words of 20 length
      char first[20]; // buffer 20 length
      char last[20]; // buffer 20 length

      printf("Enter size: ");
      scanf("%d", &size);
      printf("Enter %d words separated by space: ", size);
      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
          scanf("%s", wordArray[i]);
      }
      findWord(wordArray, size, first, last);

      printf("first = %s\n", first); 
      printf("last = %s\n", last);
  }

  void findWord(char word[][20], int size, char *first, char *last)
  {
      int i = 0;
      strcpy(first ,word[i]); // initialize to first element.
      strcpy(last ,word[i]);

      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
          if (strcmp(word[i], first) < 0)
          {
              strcpy(first ,word[i]);
          }
          else if (strcmp(word[i], last) > 0)
          {
              strcpy(last ,word[i]);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Choose yours !

Comment: I forgot about using using the strcpy() function instead of performing "=".